# Replace 2 specific functions by a generic function

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

To would create to forms with dynamic add input field.

1. I declare my formsGroup
2. Build controls
3. `addPers()` and `addBacklogs()` to create new fields.

I would replace these 2 funtions by one function and in parameter I choose which field I want to build here a prototype of what I have imagined:

```
addField(groupparam: FormGroup, fieldparam : FormArray, functionAdd: FormGroup): void {
    const control = < FormArray > this.<groupparam>.controls[fieldparam];
    control.push(this.<functionAdd()>);
}
```

Here's my **TS File**

```
export class AjoutProjetComponent implements OnInit {
    isLinear = false;
    firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
    secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
    thirdFormGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            leadProj: ['', Validators.required],
            nomProj: ['', Validators.required],
            descProj: ['', Validators.required],
            besProj: ['', Validators.required],

        });
        this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            pers: this._formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
        });

        this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            backlog: this._formBuilder.array([this.createFonct()])
        });
        console.log(this.secondFormGroup);

    }
    createItem(): FormGroup {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            poste: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    createFonct(): FormGroup {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
            fonctionnalite: ['', Validators.required],
            userStory: ['', Validators.required],
        });


    }
    deleteItem(index: number) {
        const control = < FormArray > this.secondFormGroup.controls['pers'];
        control.removeAt(index);
    }

    addPers(): void {


        const control = < FormArray > this.secondFormGroup.controls['pers'];
        control.push(this.createItem());
    }
    addBacklog(): void {


        const control = < FormArray > this.thirdFormGroup.controls['backlog'];
        control.push(this.createFonct());
    }
```

Then in HTML instead of passing `AddBacklog()` or `AddItem()` I would pass one same function with adequate params  `addField(groupparam, fieldparam, functionAdd)`

Comment: sounds like a good idea? what is your question?

Comment: How to replace these two function with only one function ? ( as specified in prototype )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you right, but I think your solution will work just fine. You could for example use strings:

```
addField(groupparam: string, fieldparam: string, functionAdd: string): void {

    const control = < FormArray > this[groupparam]controls[fieldparam];
    control.push(this[functionAdd]()>);
}
```

And then do something like

```
this.addField('secondFormGroup', 'pers', 'createItem')
```

in your code.

Whether that is the best solution overall for your use case, you have to know.

Comment: I get this error : 
`TypeError: control.push is not a function`

Comment: Them something is probably wrong with your code - it's gonna be hard to guess what that is